# asInstanceOf err in Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

[image]

#### why it is give me an error

##### I already write the code correctly

> ### code :

```
    x = 1 //true
    val x1 = x.asInstanceOf[Boolean]
    if (x1) {
      println(s"Hello, $x1")
    }
```

Comment: Because z is not a boolean, it's an Int.

Comment: Whoever told you `true` was equal to `1` was a C programmer, not a Scala programmer, and shouldn't have been making assumptions about languages they don't know.

Comment: `asInstanceOf` is not a magic cast operation, is just a _"shut up compiler I am your owner"_, at the runtime it is almost a no-op, then when the runtime does need to check the underlying class of the value and sees it is not the expected one it will crash. - TL;DR; never ever use `asInstanceOf`, you are almost never smarter than the compiler.

Comment: Mine mistake, actually i tried to write `error` and learn two languages simultaneously because of this reason, Sorry and thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the comment on this line is not correct:

```
x = 1 // true
```

`1` is not `true` because `1` is of type `Int` and `true` is of type `Boolean`. Scala is strongly typed so it doesn't automatically convert between these two types, unlike languages such as C and Python.

To fix it, just convert the `Int` to a `Boolean` like this:

```
val x1 = x != 0
```